# How can i create user using firebase in vue without sign in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I created a form to create a user profile. But I face an issue whenever I create a user. It logged in and already logged in user logout. Please help to solve this issue.

```
const successCreate = () => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, confirmPassword.value)
    .then(() => {
      db.collection('businessForm')
        .add({
          schoolName: schoolName.value,
          board: board.value,
          subjects: [
            subject1.value,
            subject2.value,
            subject3.value,
            subject4.value,
            subject5.value,
            subject6.value,
            subject7.value,
            subject8.value,
          ],
          email: email.value,
          street: street.value,
          city: city.value,
          state: state.value,
          mobile: mobile.value,
          telephone: telephone.value,
          isAdmin: true,
        })
        .then(() => {
          isLoading.value = false
          notyf.success('Account created successfully!')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          isLoading.value = false
          notyf.error('Something went wrong. Try again later!')
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      isLoading.value = false
      notyf.error('Something went wrong. Try again later!')
    })
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> How can i create user using firebase in vue without sign in?

When you create a user through the [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) method of the Client JS SDK, **on success this user will also be signed in to your application**, as explained in the doc. There is no way to avoid that.

If you want to avoid that the current user is logged out (signed out) and signed in as the newly created user, you need to implement a different approach, for example call a Cloud Function that creates the new user using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents how to build, with a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), a module for allowing end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.